# Upper triangular matrices and lower triangular matrices

Tags: matrices

I am writing a web applet that performs the LU decomposition method to break down A matrix into an `upper Triangular matrix` and `lower triangular matrix`, and I was wondering if there is a way to compute (or even approximate) the number of Upper triangular matrices and lower triangular matrices a matrix can be broken into?

Comment: The number is infinite. You may take any given decomposition $A=LU$, multiply $L$ by any $c\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ and multiply $U$ by $c^{-1}$

Comment: that's what i thought. is it always infinite, or are there any special cases? Also, I think your comment better be posted as an answer.