# Is there a standard notation for the set of lower triangular matrices?

Tags: matrices, notation

Is there a standard notation for the set of lower triangular matrices, and if so what is it. Additionally, is there a notation for the set of strictly lower triangular matrices, and if so what is it? Thanks.

Comment: If I were a textbook writer, I'll "draw" a lower triangle(with right angle in the lower left), like an alphabet.

Comment: using $L$ is fine, but the visual symbol is even better.. :P

Comment: isn't just the column number lower than the row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often the vector space of $m\times m$ lower triangular matrices with coefficients in a field $K$, or a ring $R$, is denoted by $\mathfrak{b}_m(K)$, and the subspace of strictly lower-triangualr ones by $\mathfrak{n}_m(K)$. Here the $\mathfrak{b}$ stands for the Lie algebra of the *Borel subgroup* $B$ of $GL_m(K)$, of lower-triangular invertible matrices, and the $\mathfrak{n}$ for its *nilradical* $N$. In this sense, $\mathfrak{b}_m(K)$ and $\mathfrak{n}_m(K)$ are Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}_m(K)$, where $\mathfrak{b}_m(K)$ is solvable, and $$\mathfrak{n}_m(K)=[\mathfrak{b}_m(K),\mathfrak{b}_m(K)]$$ is nilpotent. The commutator of two matrices here is given by $[A,B]:=AB-BA$. So the notation $B$ comes from "Borel", and $N$ from Nilradical, or nilpotent.

Without the context of Lie algebras, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668091/upper-triangular-matrices-and-lower-triangular-matrices).